# Spotlight search Application name conflict

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight

The use case where I see this the most is when I want to open the "Spaces" app from Spotlight. I would love to minimize the keys it takes to do this, but because other application exist with similar name (Disk Space Cleanup Management) I need to type Spaces all the way out before it shows up in the result set.

It is the only application that I launch from Spotlight that starts with "S" but Spotlight seems unable to learn this. Any way to prevent other apps from getting top billing (System Preferences, Spider, Spin Control...)

Comment: In your specific case for Spaces, have you tried assigning a keybind to spaces? You could activate it without having to use spotlight at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like spotlight...at all. I use both google [quick search](http://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/) and [alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/). they let you priorities by most used.

hope that helps